# O XML de resposta não exibe caracteres com acento

Tags: java, xml, web-service, codificação-de-caracteres, jersey

Estou usando Jersey em uma aplicação WEB. Nesta aplicação, retorno um arquivo XML às requisições dos clientes (que são web-browsers). A fim de garantir a exibição de caracteres com acento, escrevi a anotação Produces da seguinte forma:

`@Produces("text/xml ; charset=UTF-8")`

E, de fato, no XML de resposta, lê-se em seu cabeçalho a definição do charset como sendo UTF-8. O problema é que mesmo assim o browser não consegue apresentar estes caracteres especiais, aparecendo algumas coisas bem bizarras no lugar. Suspeito que o problema esteja no próprio browser, mas não faço ideia do que fazer a respeito.

Agradeço qualquer tentativa de ajuda!

Comment: Tenha certeza que o lado servidor está mesmo gerando UTF-8 e não outro encoding. Se você declarar UTF-8 mas o servidor está codificando como Latin1, vai dar este tipo de problema. Procure baixar o arquivo em vez de visualizar no browser e use um editor hexa para ver se os caracteres acentuados estão sendo recebidos com 1 byte ou 2 bytes.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Porém, tenho uma dúvida: já que o Jersey , após produzir o XML, o envia automaticamente como resposta, como faria para salvar este arquivo?

Comment: Provavelmente o que o @epx quis dizer é pra você pedir para o browser fazer download do arquivo ao invés de exibí-lo, você não precisaria salvá-lo diretamente pelo seu código.

Comment: @epx não sei bem ler esses editores hexa, mas me parece que todos os caracteres são codificados como 2 caracteres hexa (ou seja, 1 byte pra cada um)

Comment: @BrunoCésar vlw! Se puder leia a resposta acima : D